# Xcode : Storyboard and retaining data in each controller

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, uiviewcontroller, storyboard

As you can guess i am a new programmer and i have trouble getting a simple thing!
I am making an app with multiple view controllers. Each controller have textfields and UIsegmentedControl items. When i am moving from one view controller to the other (uding modal trantition if that matters), the contents of the previous one (textfield entries and segmented control option) reset to their original state. How can i make them keep their previous state?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
-(void) prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{
    bViewController *deneme = [segue destinationViewController];
    [deneme setPassedValue:label.text];
}
```

This piece of code will solve your problem, I hope. It saves the label of whatever is inside of it. And you need to add some more code to other classes.

If this code helps you tell me and I can give you the whole code.

Answer (score 0):

To save the application state you can use a model class, following the recommended MVC (model-view-controller) paradigm.
More information here: [Retain view state upon reloading](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8409316/retain-view-state-upon-reloading)

As an **alternative** you could use the `viewWillDisappear:` event to save your view state, and then restore it on the `viewWillAppear:` event.

The `viewWillDisappear:` event is fired right before the view is going to disappear, and `viewWillAppear:` is fired before the view is put on the foreground, being ideal to make any changes to the UI.

These events might have already been declared for you in your view controller, but in case they're not check the prototypes here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply but unfortunately i can not understand Apple's Documentation that much. Could you please provide an example of how a textfield's entry would be saved and restored using viewWillDisappear and viewWillAppear ?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a navigation controller to move from one view to another. 
This way, you will push your new view on top of the previous one, and when you go back, the previous view has kept its state. 
see this tutorial for more information on storyboard and UINavigationController : 
http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1